# Url pattern matching in Codename One for validating urls

Tags: java, validation, url, pattern-matching, codenameone

My Android app performs some checks on urls when opening fails.

Now I am trying to port it to iOS by Codename One.

My code is below. Note that Android code is inserted, I would like to have the Codename counterpart:

```
Boolean can = Display.getInstance().canExecute(url);
    if(can != null && can) {
        Display.getInstance().execute(url);
    } else {
        boolean validWebUrl =
                Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(url).matches(); //Android code, won't compile
        if (validWebUrl)
        {
//shows a message about activity/app not available
        else {
//shows a message about the url being not valid
        }
    }
```

As you can see the user is informed about the result, after the check, if it makes sense.
I would like to inform the user correctly about

1-the app being not available

2-the url being not valid

In fact the condition should be !validWebUrl to detect correctly that the url is of a missing app but there are overlapping cases like Apple Maps deep-links, so the best is:

```
Boolean can = Display.getInstance().canExecute(url);
    if(can != null && can) {
        Display.getInstance().execute(url);
    } else {
        ShowMessage("url not valid or app not available");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a regular expression pattern check you can use the RE class to perform a similar regular expression check but I personally dislike regex and try to go with simpler:

```
String lower = url.toLowerCase();
if(lower.startsWith("http://") || lower.startsWith("https://")) {
}
```

Comment: My Android app handles many url forms, they are found in modern mobile environments for calling app functions directly from another app or browser. And I think there are other regular expression rules other than the first part of the url.

Comment: You can use the regex here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/81aa097/core/java/android/util/Patterns.java but it's mostly there for validation not for classification. If a URL starts with http or https it isn't an intent

Comment: Thank you. We have also the Apple Maps urls which are similar to weblinks but they are sort of "intents" on Apple platforms. I do not if this makes any sense to you. See https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899-CH5-SW1

Comment: That wouldn't have been detected by the Android code you had either... Notice that if canExecute returns null the app might be installed but we failed in finding it so this is a valid case where you might want to still try running Display.execute() as it "might" work. Unfortunately, there's relatively little certainty about these things in a cross platform way

Comment: Does Display.execute() throw anything to check? (It returns void)

Comment: No. It returns immediately. We don't really know if this succeeded or failed.

Comment: As far as I understand at least there's no rutime error, right? Is it safe to use it? Furthermore, is it possible that the user get some system message? Or just nothing happens?

Comment: Yes. The app should work just fine after that assuming can is null or true. It's possible that the system will show a message but we can't guarantee it as it's out of our hands at that point.